# Efficiently creating frequency and recency columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

This is a very specific problem - my code is very slow, wonder if I'm doing something obviously wrong or there's a better way.

The situation: I have two dataframes, frame and contacts. frame is a database of people, and contacts is points of contact with these people. They look something like:

frame:

```
       name
id         
166     Bob
253   Serge
1623   Anna
766   Benna
981    Paul
```

contacts:

```
     id   type       date
0   253  email 2016-01-05
1  1623   sale 2012-05-12
2  1623  email 2017-12-22
3   253   sale 2018-02-15
```

I want to add two columns to frame, 'most_recent' and '3 year contact count', which give the most recent contact (if there is one) and the number of contacts in the past 3 years.

(frame is ~100,000 rows, and contacts is ~95,000)

So far, I'm reducing the amount of ids to iterate over, then creating a dict for each id with the right values:

```
id_list = [i for i in frame.index if i in contacts['id']]
freq_rec_dict = {i: [contacts.loc[contacts['id']==i,'value'].max(), 
                     len(contacts.loc[(contacts['id']==i)&(contacts['value']>dt(2016,1,1))])]
                 for i in id_list}
```

Then, I turn the dict into a dataframe and perform a join:

```
freq_rec_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(freq_rec_dict, orient='index',columns=['most_recent','3 year contact count'])
result = frame.join(freq_rec_df)
```

This does give me what I need, but the dictionary comprehension took 30 minutes - I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this (I will need this in the future). Any ideas would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify your output, but here goes. You should leverage the built-in `groupby` method instead of taking your data out of a frame and back into a frame and then merging

```
contacts.groupby('id')[['date','type']].max()

        date        type
id      
253     2018-02-15  sale
1623    2017-12-22  sale
```

Which you can do in one line if you need to save memory space. Again, you don't give a preferred output, so I used a left join. You could also use `'inner'` to keep only rows where records exist.

```
df=pd.merge(frame,contacts.groupby('id')[['date','type']].max(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

        name    date        type
id          
166     Bob     NaN         NaN
253     Serge   2018-02-15  sale
1623    Anna    2017-12-22  sale
766     Benna   NaN         NaN
981     Paul    NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Although this didn't actually answer the whole question, individual groupbys per column added was the right track - thank you!